encrypted partition Ubuntu installation gone from GRUB after Upgrade from Ubuntu 22 to 24
I have looked everywhere but can only find bits an pieces of the answer to this. I have a quad-boot laptop (2 windows, 1 unencrypted Ubuntu desktop, 1 encrypted Ubuntu desktop). After upgrading both Ubuntu installs to 24.04 my boot now shows the unencrypted ubuntu and windows boot manager but not the encrypted ubuntu.
This is what I THINK is happening: There are two GRUBs, and the active one was set up from the encrypted install.  I upgraded the encrypted partition first then the unencrypted one and since GRUB was upgraded as part of 24.04, the unencrypted upgrade reactivated the inactive GRUB but didn't "see" the encrypted install.  I think I need to get access to the encrypted install and run update-grub from there.
sudo -i cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme2n1p4 uproot  mount /dev/mapper/uproot /mnt mount /dev/nvme2n1p3 /mnt/boot for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do mount --rbind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done fdisk -l | grep -i efi mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi chroot /mnt update-grub
I have now been able to run update-grub from the encrypted install via chroot but it is not having any effect on grub. The output seems to indicate it is only seeing the unencrypted install, even when run from within the encrypted install.

Does this work? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736886/restore-lost-bootloader-on-a-luks-partition/736892#736892 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621

Thanks, but no.  Whether I try from a bootable USB or my unencrypted install I can get as far as decryption, but using pvscan I have no matching physical volumes.  vgscan, vgchange, and lvscan don't do anything

Does each drive have an ESP - efi system partition, so you have two ubuntu entries? Or just one which is then the last install? UEFI uses configfile to find full grub.cfg in install. Can you add a configfile into 40_custom to load grub in your encrypted install? If separate /boot, then grub.cfg there, not in / (root). https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=54&p=13787835#post13787835 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen &
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config
